# XML schema has two element types with same name in two different cases

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

One of the legacy applications XML schema definition has two types defined with same name in different cases.

```
<xsd:complexType name="effectType">
<xsd:complexType name="EFFECTType">
```

Schema validation works fine. But when I use JAXB to generate Java objects, it complains that two classes can't be generated with same.

As this schema used by existing clients, I can't change it. Is there any workaround for it so that it will allow me to generate Java objects for the schema using JAXB?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If you have solve it, How have you done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use below bindings to change the name of generated class.

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:namespace="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix">
    <bindings schemaLocation="../path of your xsd/schema.xsd">

        <bindings node="//xsd:schema//xsd:complexType[@name='EFFECTType']">
            <class name="EffectTypeTwo" />
        </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```